# Anyone know anything about Shlomo Kluger Yeshiva?

Tags: chinuch-education, history

A friend of mine said his great-grandfather taught at a yeshiva in New York called Mesivta/Yeshiva Shlomo (Solomon) Kluger.  I've heard of Rabbi Shlomo Kluger, and assume this institution was named in his memory (just like Chaim Berlin yeshiva, or Rabbi Isaac Elchanan [Spektor] Theological Seminary).  Does anyone know anything else about this place?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18763

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Located at No. 376 Houston St, the Rabbi Solomon Kluger School, a yeshiva and synagogue designed by H.I. Feldman in 1924. Apparently demolished during the widening of Houston.  Hamilton Fish Park was across the street.  The Hamilton Fish Public Library was located south of the Yeshiva, where I learned to love libraries.  There was a local police precint on the next block South.
Shalom, can you find out what his great-grandfather's name was; what subject he taught.  My brother and I were students there during the fifties.  The day was long.  Religious studies were translated into Yiddish, including the Torah with commentary, and various books of the Talmud.  Religious classes were taught in the morning, and secular studies in the afternoon.  There was a Synagogue on the premises with women separated from the men in a balcony overlooking the mens area below.  I was Bar Mitzvahed there, and tutored by the Cantor to read the Haftorah; also gave a speech in Yiddish which was reported in the Jewish Forward.  Apparently, the speech was a real tear jerker; no dry eyes left in the balcony.  Not sure how much detail you are interested in, nor how much I remember.  My brother has a better memory.  The Yeshiva was located on the lower east side, facing a park on one side, where we played during recess.  If we came back late we would get our hand rapped with a board from a chair.  The Yeshivah provided us with a hot lunch every day.  I remember a number of the instructors with great fondness.  Mr. Boland was the math and science teacher.  I learned to love reading,math, and science there.  Jewish values and traditions were taught and cultivated.

Comment: Mike, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and wow! Thanks very much for the detailed personal recollection! We'd love to have you as a fully registered member, which you can do by clicking register, above.

Answer (score 9):

I attended the Yeshiva Shlomo Kluger on Houston Street from about 1938 until 1942 when I was 8 years old. I have a picture of my class on the roof with a women teacher so it must have been the secular portion but I remember a wonderful potato soup for lunch in the winter. I wanted to have payes as I felt everyone else did but when I saw the picture only one or two boys had them.  My mother said no payes. I still remember two classmates- Yosef Marantz & a boy named Yiroel whose father had a deli near the Yeshiva.

Comment: Was this K-8?  K-12?  What age students did they have?

Comment: Yossel Lissak, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for sharing your memories! I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 6):

It was a large Yeshiva, with hundreds of students, at one time. Started in 1902 as a talmud Torah, later became full day yeshiva with secular studies as well. A lower east side (of Manhattan, NYC) institution started by Hassidic (presumably Galician) residents of the area, hence the name, after the great Galician talmid chochom.

It seems that it declined over time, and at some point there was a merger with Yeshiva Chasan Sofer, which came about in the WWII era, when Burgenland Jews, including the Mattesdorfer Rav z"l, came to the USA. But it (YRSK) had an independent existence for many years and much predated YCS in the USA, for the record.

Comment: And there's Yeshiva ChasaM Sofer vs. Yeshiva ChasaN Sofer, right?

Comment: Mordechai, welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for the excellent information! Please consider clicking on "register," above, to create an account. This will give you full access to mi.yodeya's features, and will allow you to take full credit for your contributions.

Answer (score 5):

I just now found this site. I have been looking for one that discusses Yeshiva RSK. I Attended the yeshiva starting in 1938 at 6 years of age. I have a large amount of information to add to this site. I will give th names of most of tha Rebbis in hebrew studies department and the english department plus many of the students at that time. The principal of Jewish was Rabbi Freidman and for  english it was Leonard Goldman. The first grade Rebbi was Rabbi Luria who was there for a long time and had many students. Rabbi Speigelman was second grade, third grade Rabbi Weiner, fourth Rabbi Trenkman, fifth Rabbi Rosenblum, sixth had several including Rabbi Leiberman and Rabbi Unger. Then the was Rabbi Mandelbaum, and Rabbi Yankele Flantzgraben.

Isaac, thank you. I have a wealth of information to add, just no time right now. Just acouple of little tidbits. So far as i see it all the information that has been posted so far is correct. only the library was one building over to the east of the yeshiva ans was the Hamilton Fish branch of the new york public library. The park across the street was also known as Hamilton Fish Park, it was quite a big park (2 square city blocks and had an olympic size swimming pool and also a deep water diving pool with four diving boards and one high diving board. but enough about that. Going back to the yeshiva itself just a few small items. The Marantz that Yossi Lissak mentions, I knew him, and the yisroel that he mentions could possible Izzy Suss. Also all of the people mentioned here, Mr. Boland yes, he was the science and math taecher for many years, he replaced Mr. Appplebaum, also there for many years and both very beloved to the students. Much more to come, but i will just mention a few of the names of some of the people that attended at that time so that anyone that comes here might recognize. The Goddstein brothers, Seymour Solly Willy and Milty. The Parness Brothers Duvid Buni and Shia. Thw Wulligers, Arthur Gold and his two brothers Nuchem and Shlomo. That will have to be it for now, but as i said there is much more to come. Just one thing Isaac, is there any way we can we can find out more about this site?

Comment: Abraham Horowitz, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for recording your memories here for posterity! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking on register/login, above.

Comment: I consolidated your other answer with this answer. If you want to learn more about mi.yodeya, first check out the FAQ at http://mi.yodeya.com/faq . If you have more questions about the site, please email me at info@yodeya.com.

Answer (score 4):

The Yeshiva Solomon Kluger or Shlomo Kluger moved from Houston Street at one point in the late 1950's to another location I believe on Broome street. It was located fairly east ,next to a police station and down the Street from a Bet Yaakov. It ultimately merged with the Yeshiva Chasan Sofer and served talmudim from grades kindergarten k-6. Once you reached the 7th grade you resumed your studies at the original Yeshiva Chasan Sofer on 4th street and Avenue "C"

Comment: Heschel, welcome to mi.yodeya and thank you for your additional (first-hand?) details to expand on this question. Consider registering your account fully by clicking "Register" at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the present-day Yeshiva Ch'san Sofer was originally the Mesivta of Rabbi Solomon Kluger.

Answer (score 3):

My Father Rabbi Chaim Yoel Laks z"tl, attended the Yeshiva Rabbi Shlomo Kluger in the 1920's and !930's. (He then graduated and attended Mesivta Tiferes Yerushalaim for 2 years of High School, switching to graduate from Manhattan Talmudical Academy and then Yeshiva College and REITS Rabbi Isaac Elchanan Theological Seminary where he received semicha in 1941).

He and other talmidim were very profoundly influenced by Rabbi Yankele Flatntzgraben who wasthe 8th grade Rebbe, who instilled in them a tremendous Cheishek for Torah and would learn with the talmidim on shabbosim and at all times when school was not in session at the local synagogue known as the "Nine and Nintziger", presumably located at 99 something.

Rabbi Flantzgraben's talmidim and family to this day commemorate his Yahrzheit in Brooklyn with annual siyum mishnayot and seudah in brooklyn. I have attended and met talmidim who studied through the 1960s.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and welcome to the site. I hope you stick around and enjoy it. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your [account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1376), which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: The _nein un neintziker_ was at 99 Cannon, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Family lore has it that our great grandfather, Abraham Schulder, was one of the founders of this yeshiva. Can anyone edit in to this answer more about this, for example from archival records of the yeshiva indicating information about founders?  Thanks!!

Comment: My father attended Yeshiva Shlomo Kluger in the late twenties. He definetly mentioned the family Schulder as the founding family. I am researching this yeshiva for a paper I am writing as a grad student in YU. I would appreciate it if I could get information about the Schulder family. Thanks MIMI