# Looking for more information about this "Megillah"

Tags: jewish-books, megillat-esther, jewish-american-history

My wife's grandmother passed away last year (and her grandfather many years ago) and my mother-in-law gave me this item she found while cleaning out their apartment:

[image: Case]

[image: Scroll]

It appears to be printed (on an old printing press - there are ink bleed marks in a few places) on newsprint that is glued to cloth to give the illusion of being on parchment.

The case (a thick cardboard tube) says "Mishloach Manot from [Yeshivat Rabbi Shlomo Kluger ZT"L](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/352/anyone-know-anything-about-shlomo-kluger-yeshiva)", which I know was on the Lower-East Side on New York (now "Yeshivas Chasan Sofer" of Brooklyn). Inside, below the berachot, it says that it was printed by the Hebrew Publishing Company.

Here is a Google Photos album with pictures of the entire thing: https://photos.app.goo.gl/yhBt7YtNCi15Sm6r9

Observations from the pictures:

1. It is clearly meant to be used in shul, since it says at the top to listen to the berachot from the reader, and it has the end beracha at the end.
2. It is 42 lines, which is one of the common layouts.
3. It is not a "Hamelech" layout
4. Some of the columns are a lot wider than other columns (which I have seen in some real megillot too).
5. The ten sons of Haman are spaced unevenly, which I've never seen in a real Megillah.
6. The glued seams between the sheets of paper look exactly the same as how it is done on a newspaper printing press.
7. There are small dots of ink at the top of some columns (which I assume are registration marks for press alignment) and a few places where too much ink caused artifacts.
8. To me the lettering looks similar to that which was found in the old Ktav Tikkun Kor'im (which is somehow [still](http://www.ktav.com/index.php/tikkun-torah-lakorim.html) [available](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0870685481) to [purchase](https://www.israelbookshop.com/tikkun-lakorim-ktav.html) 50+ years after publication!), except for the Berachot at the beginning and end which are in the standard font used by Hebrew Publishing Company for their Siddurim (though much larger than anything I've seen in any old Siddur).
9. It looks like the berachot may have been movable type, since some of the bigger letters have the top or bottom cracked off, but the text of the Megillah itself is clearly not movable type - it's too crooked and there are places where ascenders of one line cross descenders of the line above.

I am trying to find out more about this item, for several reasons:

1. I like old sefarim.
2. I'm curious exactly how old it is but it doesn't have a year printed on it.
3. My wife's grandparents were *extremely* Yekke (they both grew up in Germany before the war), and I don't know how they would have ended up with something like this from a Chassidish yeshiva.
4. Ignoring the case, I'm curious if this was a product that Hebrew Publishing Company actually sold, or if it was a special run done just for the Yeshiva.

Does anyone know anything about this item?

Comment: Very cool! Do you mind including pictures of the other columns and close up of the "ksav"? I wonder if we can learn anything from fine nusach points.

Comment: @DoubleAA I will see if I have time to get those pictures later today.

Comment: It's waited a century already. No rush

Comment: @DoubleAA Link to Google Photos album and some observations added above.

Comment: The 632-34 Broadway address is probably a good clue for dating this.  Wikipedia implies that they were on Broadway for a relatively short time and that they moved to Delancey in 1932.

Comment: Also maybe useful for dating: the way they spell the English name "Hebrew Publishing Company" using Hebrew letters (like you would in Yiddish?) is not at all how they spell the company name in my Birnbaum Siddur where they translate it into actual Hebrew words.

Comment: @Mike I've seen the "Yiddish" spelling of the company name in many of their siddurim, but I don't have any of those at my house to check the dates. I'll have to remember to look at shul.

Comment: Confirmed that my Siddur Tikun Meir (1935) says Delancey Street and spells the company name the same as your megillah.

Comment: In 1924, they were at 50-52 Eldridge Street https://s3.amazonaws.com/pastperfectonline/images/museum_597/010/1989083006-3.jpg . In 1928, they were at 632-34 Broadway https://s3.amazonaws.com/pastperfectonline/images/museum_597/158/1993104010.jpg .  That gets you to within a maximum 8 year window. 1924<Date<=1932

Comment: Interesting that it's so old. I guess the family must have gotten it from someone else since they came to the US in the late 1930's.

Comment: Speaking of the K'tav edition of the Tikkun Lako'rim, see here about the ERROR which is found in Parshat Vayakhel: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120915/error-in-old-ktav-edition-of-tikkun-lakorim

Answer (score 2):

While I didn't find information regarding the megillah specifically, it [seems](https://www.danwymanbooks.com/pages/books/37456/herman-klopper-henry-russotto/matnah-me-et-yeshivat-rabbeinu-shlomo-kluger) that it was customary for the yeshiva to solicit contributions through various 'gifts' given (or sold?) around the chagim. The yeshiva also considered these to be a form of community outreach. The yeshiva (naturally) struggled with money for years. In the NY Times of March 24, 1930 there's an [article](https://www.nytimes.com/1930/03/24/archives/lack-of-funds-closes-free-hebrew-school-600-pupils-at-yeshiva-rabbi.html) about the yeshiva temporarily closing down and planning a financial campaign. It's behind a paywall, so I can't see the entire article, but it's possible that the campaign included the same type of solicitation.

As @Mike [pointed out](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120742/looking-for-more-information-about-this-megillah/137184#comment399419_120742) in the comments, the range of dates for when the Hebrew Publishing Company was located at 632-34 Broadway fits the time of the NYTimes article. So it seems likely the megillah was printed and handed out as a form of soliciting donations.

Over the years, the yeshiva handed out other items related to the chagim:

In the 40s, for example, they printed haggadot, titled "מתנה מאת ישיבת רבנו שלמה קלוגער זצ"ל" (A souvenir from Yeshivat Rabbeinu Shlomo Kluger") (see [here](https://www.danwymanbooks.com/pages/books/37456/herman-klopper-henry-russotto/matnah-me-et-yeshivat-rabbeinu-shlomo-kluger) and [here](https://merhav.nli.org.il/primo-explore/search?query=any,contains,%22%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%90%20%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%92%D7%A8%20(%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A7)%22&tab=unified_tab&search_scope=uni&sortby=lso01&vid=NLI&lang=iw_IL&offset=0&cachekey=commonformats&cachekey=ag-commonFomatsItemsQuery&_gl=1*1aqjrn*_ga*MTU0NjAxNzQxNy4xNjUyNjEyMzM0*_ga_8P5PPG5E6Z*MTY5NTk3MjA4OS4zNzguMC4xNjk1OTcyMTA5LjQwLjAuMA..*_ga_8PQRSYT854*MTY5NTk3MjA4OS43NC4wLjE2OTU5NzIxMDkuNDAuMC4w*_ga_4207HLQSXF*MTY5NTk3MjA5MC43NC4wLjE2OTU5NzIxMDkuNDEuMC4w)).

Circa the late 40s or early 50s (shortly before they merged with Yeshivat Chasan Sofer) they handed out "Chanukah tokens" with a request for donations in the form of "Chanukah gelt" ([source](https://mishpacha.com/chanukah-gelt/#:%7E:text=Yeshiva%20and%20Mesifta,new%20Israeli%20currency.%E2%80%9D)):

[image: Yeshivat Rabbeinu Shlomo Kluger flier for Chanukah gelt]

The token in question probably looked something like this ([source](https://archive.org/details/Shekel1976v9n2MarApr/page/n29/mode/2up?q=%22solomon%20kluger%20school%22)):
[image: Kluger Chanukah token]