# Error in Old "Ktav" Edition of "Tikkun LaKor'im"

Tags: jewish-books, torah-reading, parashat-noach, vayakhel

I have an old copy of the old Ktav edition of "Tikkun LaKor'im, which was published in 1946.

It was printed using an copy of a hand-written Torah, of unknown provenance.

The problem with it, is that there is an ERROR [in the hand-written part] in Parshat Vayakhel (Shemot 35:11), where instead of "**את** קרסיו", it erroneously reads: "**ואת** קרסיו":

[image]

It seems that this edition is [still](http://www.ktav.com/index.php/tikkun-torah-lakorim.html) [available](https://www.israelbookshop.com/tikkun-lakorim-ktav.html) for [purchase](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0870685481).

Does anyone know if the error was repaired in subsequent printings?

**ADDENDA**:

In the same edition (1946) I have found another ERROR [in the hand-written part] in Parshat Noach (Bereishis 8:4), where instead of "ותנח **התבה**", it erroneously reads: "ותנח **תתבה**".

Note: In the edition which is found on [HebrewBooks.org](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50656&st=&pgnum=9&hilite=), the error seems to have been corrected.

Comment: @IsraelReader BTW, I have a sofer friend, who scans Torah scrolls to spot errors. I don't think it's worth it, but that way you could check their text. [I'm collecting typos in the ArtScroll Stone chumash, but they didn't seem to care despite having a long list.]

Comment: @Kazibácsi Scanning an entire Torah can be quite expensive. Meanwhile, I have done my share in helping people in correcting the mistake, in their own copies.

Answer (score 3):

In my 1969 edition the error in parsha Noach has been corrected. However, the error in parsha vayakhel is still present. Hopefully someone will have  the newest edition (2021) to check if it has been corrected.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya David and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. In particular, we are not a discussion site, so answers are meant to be answers-only and not ask new questions. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 1):

The 1969 edition in my house also has that mistake.